# R regular expression multiple lines and search for

Tags: regex, r

Does "R" language have capability to perform regular expression checks across "line breaks \n \r",
Consider below pattern : we need to find for a given "Sage score" what is "Final Score"
Sample text below

```
"access - SAFPS Members only\n Sample PreScore\n The Sage score is a generic scorecard which indicates the\n associated with a consumer by taking into consideration the\n or default.\n Identifier    Date     Final Score  Exception\n 4738998    2015-08-31  600 Debt Summary \n This section displays a summary of all the consumer's current debt obligations"
```

My code is as below

```
# Read text file, get line position of \n 
con=file("C:\\Sample.txt",open="r") 
lines=readLines(con) # line position of sage score 
index <- grep("Sage score",lines,value=FALSE,ignore.case=TRUE)
valueLine <- lines[index+2]
value line returns tokenize for 3rd token. 
4738998  2015-08-31  600
```

Question is without reading entire file do we have R regular expression across lines?

Comment: Please learn how to [format your question text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: (?m)(?:^[ \t]*) use this for multiline

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/Lm27Y2). You just need to use a PCRE regex and `(?s)` modifier.

Comment: Is it possible to explain regular expression. thanks